# Dynamically add fields in json

Tags: c#, json

I have JObject containing dynamic data for example:

```
{ "person":
  { "name": "myname",
     "city":"myCity",
     "dynamicUserData":{}
  }
}
```

now based on the city the dynamicUserData should be populated with values from Dictionary. The problem is how to add this dictionary in the dynamicUserData.

code:

```
var jobject=JObject.Parse(@"{ ""person"":  { ""name"": ""myname"", ""city"":""myCity"",""dynamicUserData"":{}}}");

var dic=new  Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var field in someFieldArray)
{
    if (field==something)
      {
        dic.Add(field,somevalue);
      }
}

//now here how can I put these values in dynamicUserData of the JObject?
```

Comment: Are you forced to use the exact JSON format as shown or are you free to format the JSON a bit different (and better to deserialize a dictionary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this without too much effort. On a JObject you can access a property the same way you would access dynamic objects. So you should be able to update the property using

```
jobject.person.dynamicUserData = new JObject(dic);
```

Or on a JObject you can access a property using jobject[key]